# jquery validation dynamic number of pair input fields comparison

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Users are allowed to add as many inputs as they want, where the input fields look like this:

```
<input id="minAge[0]"...
<input id="maxAge[0]"...

<input id="minAge[1]"...
<input id="maxAge[1]"...

<input id="minAge[2]"...
<input id="maxAge[2]"... etc
```

**Problem**

I want to validate for each pair of inputs (minAge[i],maxAge[i]) that the maxAge is greater than minAge.

**Specific solution**

```
$.validator.addMethod('lessThan', function(value, element, param) {
    if (this.optional(element)) return true;
    var i = parseInt(value);
    var j = parseInt($(param).val());
    return i < j;
}, "MinAge must be less than MaxAge");


$('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        minAge: {
            lessThan: '#maxAge'
        }
 });
```

How can I make this **solution generic**?

Comment: Also show the function that dynamically creates the new elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small fix to the solution above:

For  the jquery validation will fail.
try to use the name xxx[i] and id xxx_i, and in the rules it deals with id so change the code to:

```
var min = '#minAge_' + i,
    max = '#maxAge_' + i;

$(min).rules('add', {
    required: true,
    lessThan: max,
    // another rule, etc.
});
```

Comment: This is no different than my answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, for this plugin, you ***must*** have `name` attributes.  The jQuery Validation plugin requires *unique* `name` attributes to keep track of all inputs.

```
<input id="minAge[0]" name="minAge[0]"...
<input id="maxAge[0]" name="maxAge[0]"...

<input id="minAge[1]" name="minAge[1]"...
<input id="maxAge[1]" name="maxAge[1]"...

<input id="minAge[2]" name="minAge[2]"...
<input id="maxAge[2]" name="maxAge[2]"... etc
```

Then within whatever function you use to dynamically add fields, you would use [the `.rules('add')` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules).

```
$('#minAge[1]').rules('add', {
    required: true,
    lessThan: '#maxAge[1]',
    // another rule, etc.
});
```

Since I cannot see the function that creates your new element, I can only assume you have some kind of index variable.

```
var min = '#minAge[' + i + ']',
    max = '#maxAge[' + i + ']';

$(min).rules('add', {
    required: true,
    lessThan: max,
    // another rule, etc.
});
```

Comment: this almost works, i can see that the input elements are generated, but when i run the rules('add') I get uncaught exception: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined.

According to the documentation of rules: 
"Requires that the parent form is validated, that is, $( “form” ).validate() is called first."

All the inputs generated (only these) are included in <form> element. What could be there problem?